# Codeigniter HMVC controller doesn't print when called from another controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, hmvc

I don't understand why I get return from my controllers but it wont print a simple `var_dump`.

Steps I follow:

1. modules/controllers/home.php

   ```
   $result = modules::run("apis/c_$api/data", $parameters);
   var_dump($result); //works
   ```
2. modules/apis/controllers/c_api1.php

   ```
    function data()
    {

       #....
       case 'getDataInfo':
           echo 'baa'; //Not working
           $result = simplexml_load_string($this->api1->getDataEntry($parameters['id'], false));
           var_dump($result); //Not working
           break;
       #....

   }
   ```

Any ideas why this happens? The fact that returning `$result` works but not the `echo` or `var_dump()`

### Update

The function works because if I comment the `$result` line inside the case, I have no output. That means that the case works, but even so I don't get the `echo`

Answer (score 1):

I think that MX HMVC extension blocks in some way the output of a module when called via `Modules::run`.

Here is a small piece of MX's Modules.php, you can see that the output is not sent to the browser but returned instead:

```
ob_start();
$args = func_get_args();
$output = call_user_func_array(array($class, $method), array_slice($args, 1));
$buffer = ob_get_clean();
return ($output !== NULL) ? $output : $buffer;
```

As far as I know there is no way to send something to the output calling a module with `Modules::run` unless you want to modify the code above.

That's why you are able to print `$result` on the caller controller and not on the invoked one.

You need to return what you want to print so that you can print it on the caller side.

Comment: I'm not aware of any configuration that makes the Modules::run 'print'. Just print it on tha caller side

Comment: I understand, I wanted to print inside module just for more debugging features. But I decided to try save the data to a variable from `print` `dump` `echo` or what ever outputting function, and `print` it again inside the caller.

Comment: please add my solution that I wrote in the comment so I can accept your message.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious cause would be that `case` is not being matched.

Without seeing more of `api1.php`, I am forced to speculate.

Comment: that's the problem, IT IS matched! It returns `$result` but does not the bloody echo. LoL

Comment: If the output from `echo` is not switched off, then it must be executing another module, another function, or with different data.

Comment: no, because if I comment the `$result` line... I have no output. I know, it's strange and it's freaking me out xD

Comment: maybe you don't see output because of there is redirect in some place ? add exit(); after var_dump

Comment: check @Dalen 's answer because it seems to have a really good logic.